# Alternating series convergence test two conditions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n\geq n_0}^\infty(-1)^nb_n$ converges if $b_n$ is decreasing after some $n\geq n_0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$.

But doesn't the limit going to $0$ imply that the sequence is decreasing after some $n\geq n_0$ anyhow?
I have thought of a repeating $|\sin n|$ like sequence with a decreasing amplitude as a possible counter example, but then we can suppose that $b_n=b_{1n}+...+b_{kn}$ where each sequence is totally decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b_n=\frac  1 n$ for $n$ even and $\frac  1 {2n}$ for $n$ odd then $b_n \to 0$ but $b_n$ is not eventually decreasing.

Comment: And also in this case, the alternating series diverges.  So it really is a necessary step in the test.

Comment: thank you, I haven't thought of piecewise sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Too obvious?

$0,1/2,0,1/3,0,1/4,......$

$a_{2k-1}= 0;$ $a_{2k}=1/(k+1)$, $k=1,2,3,...$